# Treeview node with more information

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, treeviewitem

I am trying to custom info in the treeview node, so i made this class

```
Public Class TreeViewItem
    Inherits TreeNode
    Private _text As String
    Private _id As String
    Private _Data As String

    Sub New(id As String, name As String, data As String)
        MyBase.New()
        _text = Name
        _id = id
        _Data = data

    End Sub

    Public Shadows Property Text As String

        Get
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(_Data) Then
                Return String.Format("{0} -> {1}", _text, _Data)
            Else
                Return _text
            End If
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _text = Name
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property ID As String
        Get
            Return _id
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _id = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Data As String
        Get
            Return _Data
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Data = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

however when i add a node like this

```
tv.Nodes.Add(New TreeViewItem(1, "hello", "hi"))
```

the text of the node is empty, any help with why  it is not rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pretty much have to use the Text property of the base class, so try using an overload instead so that you can *set* the value:

```
Public Overloads Property Text As String
  Get
    Return MyBase.Text
  End Get
  Set(value As String)
    _text = value
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(_Data) Then
      MyBase.Text = String.Format("{0} -> {1}", value, _Data)
    Else
      MyBase.Text = value
    End If
  End Set
End Property
```

This would change your constructor to this:

```
Sub New(id As String, name As String, data As String)
  MyBase.New()
  _id = id
  _Data = data
  _text = name
  Me.Text = _text
End Sub
```

And an update to your Data property:

```
Public Property Data As String
  Get
    Return _Data
  End Get
  Set(value As String)
    _Data = value
    Me.Text = _text
  End Set
End Property
```